# Entity Framkework migaration add failing

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I am building a test app (learning) using .Net Core 2 and Angular 5.

From the root folder where csproj file is, in powerShell following execution is resulting in an error

Command

```
dotnet ef migrations add "Initial" -o "Data\Migrations"
```

Error

```
PS C:\Users\T460SU\Documents\Training\Learning-Examples\Api-Angular2018\NetCore2Angular5\TestMakerFreeApp\TestMakerFreeApp> dotnet ef migrations add "Initial" -o "Data\Migrations"
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

After going through various posts, looks like i am missing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet`. When i try to install this package, it is resulting in the following error

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet -Version 2.0.3
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet/index.json 70ms
Restoring packages for C:\Users\T460SU\Documents\Training\Learning-Examples\Api-Angular2018\NetCore2Angular5\TestMakerFreeApp\TestMakerFreeApp\TestMakerFreeApp.csproj...
Install-Package : Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0.7 to 2.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 TestMakerFreeApp -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.3 -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.7) 
 TestMakerFreeApp -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet -Version 2 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.3' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'TestMakerFreeApp'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet -Version 2 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.1203778
```

Here are the nuget packages currently installed

[image]

How can i fix this? 
**Update 1: csproj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Files not to publish (note that the 'dist' subfolders are re-added below) -->
    <Content Remove="ClientApp\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="ClientApp\app\components\about\about.component.ts" />
    <None Remove="ClientApp\app\components\login\login.component.ts" />
    <None Remove="ClientApp\app\components\pagenotfound\pagenotfound.component.ts" />
    <None Remove="ClientApp\app\components\quiz\quiz-list.component.ts" />
    <None Remove="ClientApp\app\components\quiz\quiz.component.ts" />
    <None Remove="ClientApp\app\interfaces\quiz.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\app\components\about\about.component.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\app\components\login\login.component.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\app\components\pagenotfound\pagenotfound.component.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\app\components\quiz\quiz-list.component.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\app\components\quiz\quiz.component.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\app\interfaces\quiz.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('wwwroot\dist') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />

    <!-- In development, the dist files won't exist on the first run or when cloning to
         a different machine, so rebuild them if not already present. -->
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Performing first-run Webpack build..." />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="wwwroot\dist\**; ClientApp\dist\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: After doing some further reading, looks like i don't need the package. So now i am totally lost as to what might be wrong here!

Comment: It looks like a it's not recognizing the dotnet keyword which can happen because you are ether not in the project folder i.e. `Path: ~/Solution/Project/Controllers` where the project folder is where you need to be located, so if the second `TestMakerFreeApp` is the angular app inside the project this is your problem. Are you able to run dotnet on it's own (try: dotnet -h) if they are not working it has to do something with the environment variables. If you are in the project folder and dotnet commands are working it looks like tooling is missing. Could you double check this?

Comment: I haven't setup separate projects at this time, It is a single project. The first TestMakerFreeApp is parent folder and the second one has all the files. like controllers and views etc...I'll double check after work later tonight.

Comment: I can run `dotnet -h` without any issue from the same location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please consolidate your .net core versions, so you can have a clean slate.

If you're using 2.0.x (or less), you need to add this to the project file (csproj) of the project housing your database logic

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.x" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Also, your `add migration` command needs to include your `Startup` project as well, if your database layer is a separate project. The `dotnet ef` command must be executed from the database project path, and it should look something like this:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ..\Path\To\Startup migrations add Initial -c YourDatabaseContext
```

where startup project file also needs to contain the `DotNetCliToolReference` reference.

I didn't see you mentioning database contexts, but I'm sure you must have one.

If you switch to .net core version 2.1.0, everything stays the same, except that CLI tool is now part of the core entity package, so you can remove the CLI references from csproj files.

Hope it helps

Comment: The database context is there. I have created a folder in the root called "Data" and it has the context file. Models are also in this same folder, as sub directory. It's a single project at this time. I'll do these steps after work tonight.

Comment: Added the `DotNetCliToolReference` and then performed `dotnet restore`. After that performed `dotnet ef migrations add "Initial" -o "Data\Migrations"` and it worked this time. Along with this answer, following helped as well: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8996 , check comment by `AliBayatGH` where it is stated `To install this package, add it to the DotNetCliToolReference collection in the .csproj file, You have to install this package by editing the .csproj file; you can't use the install-package command or the package manager GUI.`